# backbuffer VolatileImage resize

Tags: java, applet, double-buffering

I have a small issue regarding my backbuffer in my java applet. Currently i haven't considered the resize of my applet on runtime. Therefore the panels get resized, while my backbuffer keeps its initial size. Therefore only the part of my applet gets redrawn, which is covered by my image size. Nevertheless i have tried to reinit the image with

```
private void createBackBuffer() {
    backBuffer = this.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleVolatileImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    defaultComposite = ((Graphics2D) backBuffer.getGraphics()).getComposite();
    defaultStroke = ((Graphics2D) backBuffer.getGraphics()).getStroke();
}

// Reinit on resize
    public void adjustBackBufferSize() {
        if (backBuffer != null) {   
            backBuffer.flush();
            createBackBuffer();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately it behaves not appreciate. As soon as the user starts dragging to resize the browser window, the recreation means having no backbuffer to draw for a small amount of time. Therefore the panel is flickering, either having the gray background, panels used to have or the actual drawing i am about to render.

I considered setting an offset onto width and height while resizing to lower the flickering behavior, but this still does not seem to be a proper way, just a workaround.

Any suggestions to resize without flickering?!

Kind regards.

Comment: *"Currently i haven't considered the resize of my applet on runtime."*  Sun intended applets to be of fixed size.  Applet resizing in web pages has always been unreliable.  I would not spend the time worrying about it.

Comment: Well Nevertheless JApplet has a function to forward the resize action of the user. Anyway its still important to me. I can actually increase the initial size, but thats still nothing i feel good with.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem: Unwanted Repaints

The flickering occurs because the panel is repainting itself. These repaints are unwanted since you don't want the window to start flickering. If you disable automatic repainting then you will be in control of when your applet will repaint. What you can do is change your code to perform a repaint once the new buffer has been initialized.

### Solution, Part 1: Disable Repainting

You should try the following:

```
setIgnoreRepaint(true);
```

If that doesn't do anything, try adding this to the class with your `main()` method:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
}
```

This should disable automatic repainting for you, but it could be that some other components needs to be instructed to not automatically repaint themselves too. If you post an SSCCE, I can help you more. Also, run some tests to see if your application still works correctly--you may need to add some `repaint()` calls, for example during minimizing and restoring.

### Solution, Part 2: Repaint on Demand

Since you want the repaint to happen after the `backBuffer` gets initialized, change your code to:

```
    // Reinit on resize
    public void adjustBackBufferSize() {
        if (backBuffer != null) {   
            backBuffer.flush();
            createBackBuffer();
            repaint();
        }
    }
```